# How to set a specific version of exec_depend in ROS package.xml

Tags: package, ros

I was trying to set a specific version of a ROS package in `package.xml`:

```
<?xml versioin="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
    <name>colin_bringup</name>
    <version>0.2.9</version>
    <description>This is colin bringup package</description>
    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

    <!--This is a personal package-->
    <!--I want to set this package version to robot_driver >= 1.0.2-->
    <exec_depend>robot_driver</exec_depend>
    <export>
    </export>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [REP140](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#build-depend-multiple) it is possible to use inside `exec_depend` the same version attributes as in `build_depend`, such as:

```
<build_depend version_gte="1.1" version_lt="2.0">genmsg</build_depend>
```

The attributes are:

```
version_lt="VERSION" (optional)

The dependency to the package is restricted to versions less than the stated version number.

version_lte="VERSION" (optional)

The dependency to the package is restricted to versions less or equal than the stated version number.

version_eq="VERSION" (optional)

The dependency to the package is restricted to a version equal than the stated version number.

version_gte="VERSION" (optional)

The dependency to the package is restricted to versions greater or equal than the stated version number.

version_gt="VERSION" (optional)

The dependency to the package is restricted to versions greater than the stated version number.
```

Comment: But this package is only needed in exec_depend, and I tried to edited this attributes on exec_build label. 
I used `rosversion` to check robot-base version is 1.0.3,
I set `<exec_depend version_gte="1.0.5">robot_base</exec_depend>`,
after that, I tried `catkin_make`, it passed, no error message.